# i cloned a flutter project from github into vscode running but when i am running it i am getting this error:

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

i cloned a flutter project from github into vscode running but when i am running it i am getting this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'.
photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:89
  }) : super(debugOwner: debugOwner, kind: kind);
                                     ^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/kanishka/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1350

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/kanishka/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 57s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i tried upgrading the dependencies but it did'nt work

Comment: Run flutter doctor and share console here